# Microsoft Service Bus 1.1 configuration wizard fails - The LDAP server is unavailable

Tags: servicebus

I use the service bus configuration wizard and, while everything seems fine during validation, in the end I get this:

```
    [Error] [20/2/2014 11:07:14 ]: System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: The server could not be contacted. ---> System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalServerDownException: The server could not be contacted. ---> System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapException: The LDAP server is unavailable.
       at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.Connect()
       at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.SendRequestHelper(DirectoryRequest request, Int32& messageID)
       at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.SendRequest(DirectoryRequest request, TimeSpan requestTimeout)
       at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.ReadServerConfig(String serverName, ServerProperties& properties)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.ReadServerConfig(String serverName, ServerProperties& properties)
       at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoServerVerifyAndPropRetrieval()
       at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext..ctor(ContextType contextType, String name, String container, ContextOptions options, String userName, String password)
       at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext..ctor(ContextType contextType)
       at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.get_Current()
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Commands.ServiceBusBaseCmdlet.CreateAdminGroup(String adminGroup)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Commands.NewSBFarmBase.ProcessRecordImplementation()
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Commands.ServiceBusBaseCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
       at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConfigWizard.CommandletHelper.InvokePowershell(Command command, Action`3 updateProgress)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConfigWizard.ProgressPageViewModel.CreateSBFarm(FarmCreationModel model)
```

Ideas anyone?

**EDIT:**

I have tried disabling my firewall completely, I enabled and started the "SQL Server Browser" service, tested my credentials, and I am completely clueless...

(I also have the SQL Server instance on my local machine, if that matters)

**EDIT2:**

After trying with another user account (the one I was inserting in the wizard) I got this:

```
    [Error] [21/2/2014 10:24:39 πμ]: System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: Starting service Service Bus Gateway on machine TURBOX-PC failed: Time out has expired and the operation has not been completed. ---> Microsoft.ServiceBus.Commands.Common.Exceptions.OperationFailedException: Starting service Service Bus Gateway on machine TURBOX-PC failed: Time out has expired and the operation has not been completed. ---> System.ServiceProcess.TimeoutException: Time out has expired and the operation has not been completed.
       at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus desiredStatus, TimeSpan timeout)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Commands.Common.SCMHelper.StartService(String serviceName, Nullable`1 waitTimeout, String hostName)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Commands.Common.SCMHelper.StartService(String serviceName, Nullable`1 waitTimeout, String hostName)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Commands.ServiceBusConfigHelper.StartSBServices(String hostName, Nullable`1 waitTimeout)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Commands.AddSBHost.ProcessRecordImplementation()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConfigWizard.CommandletHelper.InvokePowershell(Command command, Action`3 updateProgress)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConfigWizard.ProgressPageViewModel.AddSBNode(FarmCreationModel model, Boolean isFirstCommand)
```

**EDIT :**

Using a different account and different port numbers (the default didn't work) I have managed to configure the SB, but now for some reason it still tries to use the default ports...
Does this thing work on ports other than the default ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are logged in as a domain user you need contact with the domain controller. This is what is failing for you.

I got this same error when trying to install service bus on my work laptop at home. When back at the office the installation was successful.

Some additional information about system requirements here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn441409.aspx